# Angular2 - make long running process run asynchronously (not HTTP or JSONP, etc)

Tags: angular, asynchronous, typescript, promise, observable

I am doing something that seems atypical - I am writing an browser app that will do a lot of heavy processing itself, rather than sending that work off to a server and waiting for a response. Basically the user selects a file which my app then reads in (never sends it to server) and does a lot of processing on it. Depending upon the size of the file, this processing can take anywhere from 2 to 10 seconds. I find TONS of examples of how to use Promises and Observables when the function you are calling sets up the P or O for you (like with Http.get()).

But what if the process you want to run asynchronously is code internal to the app? I succeeded in creating a method in my service that retuns a Promise like this:

```
// these methods both defined inside my service class:
loadAsync(fileBuffer: string): Promise<MyObject> {
  return Promise.resolve(this.loadFile(fileBuffer));
}

loadFile(fileBuffer: string):MyObject {
  // long running function
  return object;
}
```

But when I use console log messages to see what's going on, it's obvious that my promise wrapper function is not running the loadFile method asynchronously as I need it to.

As background, I am using:
- angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.24
- angular 2.3.1
- typescript 2.0.3
- zone.js 0.7.2
on Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: Async doesn't mean parallel, it means schedule into the event queue for later execution. When it then actually is executed, nothing else is executed until all sync parts are completed, during this time your browser tab will be unresponsive. If you want parallel execution use WebWorkers. Angular provides built-in WebWorker support, but I don't know details.

Comment: Thanks Günter - that is indeed the distinction I was missing.